# JavaScript Object Notation Web Token Expiring Time Checker

Tags: api, jwt, access-token

How do I make sure the user access token does not expire if the user is still making requests to the system APIs/server?

Is it possible to refresh the `JWT` expiring date per every request the user makes to the server?

Answer (score 0):

*OAuth2* uses both a short lasting *access token*, which contains user data, and a long lasting *refresh token*, which is used to ask for a fresh *access token*.

Just to point out that you can change the data of a *JWT* (or more accurately create a new one) only on the server side. Even if its data is publicly accessible, its signature is based on its content. So if its content is modified, it has to be signed again with the private key, or it will be invalid.
Its objective is not to hide data (except in the case of JWE/JWS), but to ensure the server that receives it along with any client request that it is authentic (created by the server, thanks to its private key, or by a third party authentication service).
(sorry if it was already clear for you)

If you're implementing some specific and limited security, and want something simple, you can keep on the server side some info (in a DB table for instance) about the token expiration, and send a new one along with a response if you detect it's about to expire (and if the token of the *Authorization* header is OK).

Otherwise, you can implement some client side polling, asking regularly for a new token (or better, but more complex, server push).

I also worked on a solution where the implementation was to fail and retry: if the token was refused by the server (after 5 minutes), the client contacted the auth service (which had a registry of the provided tokens, with a longer expiration time), which provided a new token. After that, the client retried the request.

I've also worked on an implementation where, as you propose, new tokens were sent with each response... Somewhat. We also kept the tokens list in a registry, just to be sure that only one new token would be sent for a token received (to ensure this system wouldn't multiply the authorized tokens). Upon reception, the previous tokens were disabled (but had a grace period: they were still valid for a minute to ensure that parallel calls would make it to the server), while providing a new token. This system also ensured that the app wouldn't be usable by the same user on different devices at the same time (tokens were scoped per user, any previous user tokens were deleted).
Just note that with such a system, developping, debugging, replaying requests becomes a pain...

Not being a security expert, I couldn't guarantee my answer is bullet proof. Maybe you'll get better comments soon.

There are common security patterns such as OAuth, on which you could find info on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page), the security guys bible, and third party solutions that do a lot for you, such as [Auth0](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/) (have a look at their artcles, they're a gold mine), but software/security architects never miss an opportunity to design a custom security implementation of their own (...and reinvent the wheel).